# About Sobolev Space definition.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I would like to know if this two definitions for Sobolev Spaces are equivalent:
$H_2^m([a,b]):=\{f: f',...,f^{(m-1)} \text{absolutely  continuous}, \int _a^b (f^{(m)})^2dx<\infty \}$

and  $H_2^m([a,b])$ contains all functions $f$ such that $D^\mu f \in L_2([a,b])$ for $\mu=0,1,...,m$

The first definition requires the $m$th derivative to be square integrable, while in the second one all derivatives (up to order m) must belong to $L_2([a,b])$ and no continuity is required. 
I guess it has to do with the fact that *absolute continuity* is required, but I want to be sure that both are valid.
Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @orange https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: Or could it be that the second is not actually a definition in the formal sense, but just a state? It came to my mind that maybe the author was not actually defining the space but just making a characterization

Comment: @orange this is the article where the second statement is made, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019250217452